# drag and drop between textblocks

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I want to drag text from one textblock to another, and have the pointer change to the an image of the dragged text whilst moving. in a WFP program on Visual Studio 2015, using VB

I've got it half working by using the PointerPressed event in the source textblock and the PointerReseled in the destination. But this doesn't change the mouse pointer. also not sure its the best way to go about the task.

Any help welcome.

**Update**
I've set the CANDRAG=TRUE on the source, and ALLOWDROP=TRUE on the destination, and this gives the visual feedback I require, but doesn't allow me to drop on the textblock.

Answer (score 0):

There is a class System.Windows.DragDrop to do the task. It has a few enumeration values to influence the pointers appearance.

The class UIElement has events to react to:

```
DropEvent (Which will be the one you should react to)
DragOverEvent
DragEnterEvent
DragLeaveEvent
```

Comment: Can you give a simple example please?

Comment: I've added code to the target textblock DROP event but it doesn't fire.

Comment: I assume the drop event will only get fired if DragDrop.DoDragDrop is called first. I apologize for the missing example, but I have no experience using VB. I use the same classes in C#. You should start the DragDrop in MouseMove or ButtonDown on your source object.

Comment: Can't find a doDragdrop event/method

Comment: I found this one: [DoDragDrop](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.dragdrop.dodragdrop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1)

Comment: Which doesn't seam to exist in Universal apps for windows 10!